# Why are most questions in unanswered answered?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I just had a look at https://askubuntu.com/unanswered and I saw that most of the questions were answered. Not recently either. Some of them were answered two months ago. Why is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answers need upvotes to be considered answered.

So if a question has like 3 answers and none of them have upvotes then it's still considered unanswered because no one in the community thinks the answers deserve an upvote.

This is why voting is crucial for the health of the site:

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. Thank you. :)

Comment: I think, the term should be changed to an un-ambiguous word. Because, none of the answers are considered "not an answer",So they should be considered answer (if they aren't answer, then what are they?) IMO. "No upvoted answer" or somewhat similar can be used.